# Hyper Ledger Composer , call REST API server side or client side

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm working on Hyper Ledger Composer and integrating the REST API in a nodejs web app "using js  client side to call the API "
and I'm wondering how can I keep some interface private and prevent from show and post to it .
Should I simply call the api server side before or is there an elegant way ?

Comment: your Node JS app is the REST client. Your app user will use a business network card (either local or in the Cloud say using  cloud object datastore such as Redis storage (eg)) to access the business network. Are you talking about: securing the 'interface' between the user -> app and app -> REST server ? Your question needs context, and isn't clear. Transport Layer Security TLS security of your connections is the obvious means to do what you request.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony , thank you a lot for your reply ,
Actually should I use  HLC REST API : 
REST API -> web client  "in this case how to avoid access to certain interface" 
or     REST API -> Server Side nodejs -> web client , thank you again , still confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect access to the REST APIS, you can implement an authentication strategy - see here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html and https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html (the latter requires that authentication is enabled).

A tutorial on using one such strategy - eg using Google OAUTH2 as an auth provider - is shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to develop your own rest api using NodeJs sdk.
You can connect to the network using Cards and perform any action using BusinessNetworkConnection class and factory object.

Read [https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/applications/node][1]